# Skewness and Kurtosis Calculation on BigQuery and Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, statistics

How can I create Skewness and Kurtosis statistical functions, which are like Python scipy/pandas on Big query?

I have researched UDFs, but I know that these structures do not allow aggregated and windowed operations. These two statistical calculations are not included in Big Query by default.

Answer (score 3):

You won't need a UDF for that - the definition of the [statistical moments](https://link.medium.com/GEAualoauvb) isn't so complex.

The first two may have built in versions, but let's cover them as well as the two you're interested in:

#### mean

The first statistical moment is the mean. As a simple aggregate value: `SUM(field)/COUNT(field)`

You could create a new column with this value using a window function (which you mentioned)

```sql
    SELECT
        COUNT(field) OVER(w) AS n,
        SUM(field) OVER(w) / COUNT(field) OVER(w) AS mean
      FROM
        some_table
```

Here `w` would be the definition of a window. I have added a field `n` for later convenience.

#### variance

Okay, so now we have the mean. The variance is the second statistical moment, and builds on the definition of the mean:

```sql
    SELECT
        POW(SUM(field - mean), 2) OVER(w) / n AS variance
      FROM
        some_table
```

You can see that defining `n` previously made this more concise.

The square root of the variance (`SQRT(variance) AS sdev`) is the standard deviation. Let's also add this `sdev` column for future convenience.

#### skewness

On to the third moment! The skewness continues to build on the first two moments:

```sql
    SELECT
        POW(SUM(field - mean), 3) OVER(w) / (n * POW(sdev, 3)) OVER(w) AS skewness,
      FROM
        some_table
```

(note how defining `sdev` makes this more concise)

#### kurtosis

And so we arrive at my favourite, the fourth statistical moment, the one with a name that makes you sound clever if you know it. [There are actually two slightly different definitions](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35b.htm), but moving between them is simple.

```sql
    SELECT
        POW(SUM(field - mean), 4) OVER(w) / (n * POW(sdev, 4)) OVER(w) AS kurtosis,
      FROM
        some_table
```

And we could define `kurtosis - 3 AS x_kurtosis` if we prefer that definition (kurtosis of a Normal distribution is 3, so subtracting 3 makes it 0 - then a kurtosis of, say 3.1 is an 'excess kurtosis' of 0.1).